# How to remember item "physical" position in recyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a dialog with `RecyclerView` of IDs in it. While I was choosing an id it changes its background. I did it by replacing adapter where I am putting newly selected position. And in my adapter item layout was chosen by its position where if equals to selected, it has another layout.

So after resetting a new adapter to recycler it losses current scroll position. I tried to use `scrscrollToPosition`, but it still not perfect, due to the situation that scrolled position is always on a beginning of `RecyclerView`.

So as I understand the problem I need to remember reference or some other scrolling data for setting it on the new adapter.

So If someone knew relevant `RecyclerView` methods or good practice for this problem, it would be nice =)

I don't think that here I need some code, cause it more practice question, but if someone need it I would add it.

Update: Meantime I found this method for getting offset of `RecyclerView` but still looking how to use this data in new adapter.

```
int offset = recyclerViewDialog.computeHorizontalScrollOffset();
```